# Find next empty column to write query data in Excel using Python (

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I'm using pandas to fetch query results from Oracle and **I want to write it to an Excel file and put the data in the first column that is empty**, so the first time should be Column A, next time I run this program it should add the data into Column B etc.

I'm using openpyxl to write this data using the max_row / max_column method I found. I've been searching for awhile and cannot find a way to use openpyxl to do it in the next empty column though.

```
main_file = glob('C:\\Users\\dataTemplate.xlsx')[0]

nwb = load_workbook(main_file)
nws = nwb.worksheets[0]

copy_file = (
    r'C:\\Users\\queryData.xlsx')

cwb = load_workbook(copy_file)
cws = cwb.worksheets[0]

#Updated
nmc = nws.max_column + 1

mr = cws.max_row
mc = cws.max_column

for i in range(1, mr + 1):
    for j in range(1, mc + 1):
        c = cws.cell(row=i, column=j)
        nws.cell(row=i, column=nmc + j).value = c.value
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As you use `pandas`, you can use the following code:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    wb = writer.book
    ws = wb.active
    df.to_excel(writer, startrow=ws.min_row-1, startcol=ws.max_column, index=False)
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use `ws.max_column` and `ws.max_row`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
```

Output:

```
>>> ws.max_row
5

>>> ws.max_column
9

>>> get_column_letter(ws.max_column)
'I'
```

My excel file:

[image]

Comment: Aren't I already using max_column and max_row in my current code? I just have it named mr and mc.

Comment: Oh sorry! So what is your problem?

Comment: Why don't you use `for j in range(mc + 1, mc + 1 + len(???) + 1):`?

Comment: I don't follow..  What should I be adding in the ??? area?

Comment: You want to write in the first column, right? But what do you want to write from this column?

Comment: I want to write in the first column that is empty each time.

Comment: I think I just figured it out...

```nmc = nws.max_column + 1
nws.cell(row=i, column=nmc + j).value = c.value ```

This skips the first blank but that works well for what I need.

Comment: That's right! Just use `column=nmc + j - 1` or start your range from 0 and not 1.

Comment: yeah I just don't know how to start on Column A and then the next time, use the first blank column. Currently when I do this with a fresh spreadsheet it loads the data in Column C

Comment: Using my update code, if I use a new spreadsheet, it's start at the first row and column.

Comment: It got me closer, but still using ```column = nmc + j -1``` it put the data into column B. Doing -2 got me to Column A but then when I write to it again since data already exists, it overwrites 1 column of that data.

Comment: Did you try my code? Does it work?

Comment: Are you referring to this? ```for j in range(mc + 1, mc + 1 + len(???) + 1)```- I don't understand what's supposed to go into the len() function

Comment: No check my answer, I updated it.

Comment: No, that data started on column H...